# Site maps are being generated automatically with /pub/media in the URL giving 404 errors

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

Our sitemaps are generated automatically daily and split in to 22 files, https://www.oursite.nl/pub/media/sitemap-1-1.xml - https://www.oursite.nl/pub/media/sitemap-1-22.xml
The issue is the links are generated with /pub in the URL which navigates to a 404.

When we regenerate the xml's VIA Marketing > SEO & Search > Site Map they are generated correctly without the /pub https://www.oursite.nl/media/sitemap-1-1.xml

Has anyone else faced this issue? I'm not sure what other information I can post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't faced this issue but I know that your webserver should have it's entry-point in the /pub folder. I think if you adjust this you wouldn't face this problem.